# Return a value based of three different ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get Column H to populate with either SV, LV, or DS bases on a range of values in Columns C, D, E.

If C is between 270-300, and D is between 3-5, and E is between 900-2000, return a value of SV in column H.

If C is between 300-375, and D is between 3-5.2, and E is between 900-1700, return a value of LV in column H.

If C is between 375-420, and D is between 5.3-7.9, and E is between 900-1700, return a value of DS in column H.

I have tried nested IF AND statements, but I cannot seem to get it right. I'm ok doing this in VBA, if that would work better. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this formula.

```
=IF(AND(C1>=230,C1<300,D1>=3,D1<5,E1>=900,E1<2000),"SV",IF(AND(C1>=300,C1<375,D1>=3,D1<5.2,E1>=900,E1<1700),"LV",IF(AND(C1>=375,C1<420,D1>=5.3,D1<7.9,E1>=900,E1<1700),"DS","na")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a more dynamic way to get the result you want using `INDEX` and `SUMPRODUCT`.

[image]

The formula I entered from `cell H2` is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($P$2:$P$4,SUMPRODUCT(--(C2>=$J$2:$J$4)*--(C2<=$K$2:$K$4)*--(D2>=$L$2:$L$4)*--(D2<=$M$2:$M$4)*--(E2>=$N$2:$N$4)*--(E2<=$O$2:$O$4)*(ROW($P$2:$P$4)-1))),"")
```

What this does is to use `SUMPRODUCT` to match the criteria and then use `INDEX` to retrieve the corresponding outcome.  You can try and see if this works for you.

Comment: when you multiply arrays, `TRUE` and `FALSE` become `1` and `0` so no need for any of those `--`

Comment: I know that @CallumDA.  To transform to `1 and 0` is easier to evaluate your formula which makes it fits in that small window better than many `TRUE and FALSE` floating around.  Just personal preference but that `--` is not required as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried these formulas and they are returning invalid.  I'm using two sheets and trying to reference data from both to return a value.

If "EID" on sheet 1 is found on column A of sheet 2; and
If "column B of sheet 2) is = "1"
Then return "date of completion" from sheet 2, otherwise return "not complete"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).